# How to save sklearn model on s3 using joblib.dump?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, scikit-learn, joblib

I have a sklearn model and I want to save the pickle file on my s3 bucket using joblib.dump

I used `joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl')` to save the model locally, but I do not know how to save it to s3 bucket.

```
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket').Object("model.pkl").put(Body=joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl'))
```

I expect the pickled file to be on my s3 bucket.

Comment: does this result in an error? what is the behavior you are seeing?

Comment: joblib.dump returns a list of filenames... `Body` needs to be a bytes or a file-like object that can be read.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a way that worked for me. Pretty straight forward and easy. I'm using `joblib` (it's better for storing large sklearn models) but you could use `pickle` too.
Also, I'm using temporary files for transferring to/from S3. But if you want, you could store the file in a more permanent location.

```
import tempfile
import boto3
import joblib

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
bucket_name = "my-bucket"
key = "model.pkl"

# WRITE
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    joblib.dump(model, fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    s3_client.put_object(Body=fp.read(), Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)

# READ
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    s3_client.download_fileobj(Fileobj=fp, Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
    fp.seek(0)
    model = joblib.load(fp)

# DELETE
s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
```

Comment: Should be ```s3_resource.meta.client.put_object()```

Comment: Worked with **s3 = boto3.client('s3')** for me to use put_object

Comment: Miraculously, this solution works for saving/loading both sklearn and Tensorflow models! Thank you!

Comment: It does not worked properly for me. It dumped a file with 0bytes and the load raised an EOFerror. However, @nbeuchat answer below worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the [s3fs](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library.

```
import joblib
import s3fs
import os

# Write
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
output_file = os.path.join("s3://...", "model.joblib")

with fs.open(output_file, 'wb') as f:
    joblib.dump(clf, f) 

# Read
with fs.open(output_file, 'rb') as f:
    clf = joblib.load(f)
```

Comment: Thank you, it's simple and it works.

Answer (score 4):

Use following code to dump your model to s3 location in .pkl or .sav format:

```
import tempfile
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# you can dump it in .sav or .pkl format 
location = 's3://bucket_name/folder_name/'
model_filename = 'model.sav'  # use any extension you want (.pkl or .sav)
OutputFile = location + model_filename

# WRITE
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    joblib.dump(scikit_learn_model, fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    # use bucket_name and OutputFile - s3 location path in string format.
    s3.Bucket('bucket_name').put_object(Key= OutputFile, Body=fp.read())
```

Comment: I think location should contain just the folder name inside the bucket i.e `location = 'folder_name/'`. That is what worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Just correcting Sayali Sonawane's answer:

```
import tempfile
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

# you can dump it in .sav or .pkl format 
location = 'folder_name/' # THIS is the change to make the code work
model_filename = 'model.sav'  # use any extension you want (.pkl or .sav)
OutputFile = location + model_filename

# WRITE
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    joblib.dump(scikit_learn_model, fp)
    fp.seek(0)
    # use bucket_name and OutputFile - s3 location path in string format.
    s3.Bucket('bucket_name').put_object(Key= OutputFile, Body=fp.read())
```